# Variadic Functions

Tags: c, variadic-functions

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void varfun(int n,...){
va_list ptr;
int num;
va_start(ptr,n);
num=va_arg(ptr,int);
printf("\n%d",num);

}


int main(int argc, char **argv){

varfun(3,7.5,-11.2,0.66);

return 0;
}
```

Look at the above code, i expect the output to be the first variable parameter value casted to int i.e 7.5 casted to int, i.e. 7. But the output is 0.
What is wrong in this?

Comment: Try "num = (int)va_arg(ptr, double);" instead of "num = va_arg(ptr, int);" and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Patrick87: Yes, but the cast is unnecessary; `va_arg(ptr, double)` is of type double, which can be *implicitly* converted to int.

Comment: @Keith: Unnecessary, perhaps, but it's not hurting a thing, and is self-documenting. I'd put it in every time.

Comment: Keith, Patrick:  You are BOTH right: the cast isn't necessary, compiler will _implicitly_ perform it and the _explicit_ cast is useful, it records the fact that the programmer'sintent is indeed to downcast to an int.  As they say, "What goes without saying also goes if one says it".

Comment: @Patrick87: I disagree.  Casts should *always* be viewed with suspicion.  In this case, suppose you later modify the program so that `num` is of type `long`.  Without the cast, the assignment just works.  With it, you have to remember to change `(int)` to `(long)`; the compiler probably won't even warn you if you forget.

Comment: @Keith: Let's agree to disagree, then.

Comment: btw, you _must_ have a call to `va_end` in the function calling `va_start`, or face possible undefined behavior

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `va_arg` does not **convert** the argument. It **interprets** it as the indicated type. *And if the types don't match, you invoke Undefined Behaviour.*

```
va_arg(ptr, int); /* take the next 4 bytes from the stack and interpret them as an `int` */
va_arg(ptr, double); /* take the next 8(?) bytes ... and interpret as double */
(int)va_arg(ptr, double); /* ... convert to int */
```

Also note the cast isn't really needed in your snippet. The compiler will convert automatically

```
void varfun(int n, ...) {
    va_list ptr;
    int num;
    va_start(ptr, n);
    num = va_arg(ptr, double); /* interpret as double, then convert to int */
    printf("%d\n",num);
}
```

Comment: It might not even do that (though it probably does).  The behavior is undefined.  For example, and implementation might pass `int` and `double` arguments via different mechanisms; looking for an `int` might give you pure garbage, not just a reinterpreted `double`.  (Bottom line: get the types right.)

Comment: Yes, right. Thanks @Keith ... I was updating my answer (ninja-edit) as you were typing the comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Your second argument, `7.5` is of type `double`, but your call `va_arg(ptr, int)` is treating it as an int.  This means undefined behavior.

A variadic function has to be able to figure out the number and type(s) of the arguments -- and if the caller lies, you're out of luck.  `printf`-like functions do this via the format string; other functions might treat all their arguments as pointers and use a trailing null pointer as a sentinel.

Comment: Your answer is as valid and useful as the other ones!  I'm not the downvoter but I just +1 to make it fair.

Comment: Thanks.  (I really wasn't trolling for upvotes; I was actually hoping for constructive criticism.)

Comment: yeah, same here, I'm not in to catch up with Jon Skeet ;-) but I'm always peeved when I see downvotes without a constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really *casting*  but merely "reading the first few bytes" (*) of a *floating point* variable and considering it an integer.

You need to read this argument as its actual type, a double, and then casting as an int.

```
num = (int) va_arg(ptr, double);
```

(*) Technically, the behavior associated with va_arg(ptr, wrong_type) is `undefined`.  "reading the first few bytes" is a figure of speech, only describing what *typically* may happen.  No serious program should rely on such implementation details.

Comment: The cast isn't necessary; a `double` can be implicitly converted to an `int`.  (This could be significant if the program is later changed, for example if `num` becomes a `long`.)

Comment: @keith Thompson: ...and when this hypothetical change of the type of num occurs, one should find all references to num and adapt accordingly. The printf format string for eg. may not follow suite and god know the all other kinds of subtle issues one would leave the program open to, without a cautious review.  So, you are quite correct: CASTs, _in general_, are a SMELL but in this instance the validity of either approach is a draw.  I tend to favor being explicit; the odds having to make num a long are probably less than these of the original intent being misunderstood at first.

Answer (score 0):

It won't automatically cast the value 7.5 into an `int` like that.  You'll need to use `va_arg` to retrieve the value as a `double` and then do the cast afterwards.

`va_arg(ptr,int)` is actually expecting the value stored at `ptr` to be a bitwise representation of an `int`, and it's not.

Comment: It's a `double`, not a `float`.  The constant `7.5` is of type `double`.  And even if the argument were `7.5f`, variadic arguments undergo the default argument promotions which, among other things, promote `float` to `double`.